# TypeError: Model.findById is not a function (Rare error)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, mongoose

This happend so rarely, but it's stressing.

I got this Schema and Model:

```
//Product Schema
let ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  inStock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  barCode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});
```

and export like this:
`module.exports = v1_connection.model('Product', ProductSchema);`

So, in the same folder but another file, I got this two Schema (The first is embedded in the second):

```
/*
  Product in Sale Schema
*/
let InSaleProductSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    unique: true
  },
  qty: {
    type: Number,
  },
  total: {
    type: Number,
  },
  inSale: {
    type: Boolean
  }
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});

/*
  Sale Schema
*/
let SaleSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  products: [InSaleProductSchema],
  total: {
    type: Number,
  },
  isComplete: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});
```

Well, the problem it's specified in a pre 'save' hook, who want's to substract the needed quantity from the product saved document. In this line it's the problem

```
// Create and execute the query to find the product by de product ID
let query_product = Product.findById(product_id);
```

Always, when I want't to run the hook, throw me an error with this message:

`TypeError: Product.findById is not a function`

So. . . what's wrong?

** If you ask how I import the product Model: `const Product = require('./product');` **

Comment: Are you doing that in your presave hook?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep seperate file for each schema like that:

**ProductSchema.js:**

```
//Product Schema
let ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {    type: String,    required: true  },
  description: {    type: String  },
  price: {    type: Number,    required: true  },
  inStock: {    type: Number,    required: true  },
  barCode: {    type: String,    required: true,    index: true,    unique: true  }
 }, { timestamps: true });

// creating model
module.exports = mongoose.model('ProductSchema', ProductSchema);
```

**InSaleProductSchema.js:**

```
/*
  Product in Sale Schema
*/
let InSaleProductSchema = new Schema({
    product: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', unique: true },
    qty: { type: Number, },
    total: { type: Number, },
    inSale: { type: Boolean }
}, {
        timestamps: true
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('InSaleProductSchema', InSaleProductSchema);
```

**SaleSchema.js:**

```
/*
  Sale Schema
*/
let SaleSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    products: [InSaleProductSchema],
    total: { type: Number, },
    isComplete: { type: Boolean, default: false }
}, {
        timestamps: true
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('SaleSchema', SaleSchema);
```

And here your index file :

**index.js:**

```
const Product = require('./product');
// Create and execute the query to find the product by de product ID
let query_product = Product.findById(product_id).exec();
console.log(query_product);
```

Hope above code will work for you:

Comment: Ok, understood. Let me try the solution & I give you feedback